# Excel Sumif the a number number i am looking for is in a string

Tags: excel

I want to search a string delimited with a comma and find the numbers.
Currently my implementation only works for 0-9.  when I get to 10 it breaks.  10 also counts for 1, so the 1 sum is too much.

```
=SUMIF(B5:B64,"*" &I15&"*",C5:C64)
```

A       B       C

PAY:    FLAGS:  PROB:

700     1,      8.00000000000E-3

750     11,     2.20000000000E-2

800     1,11,   1.60000000000E-2

ColI    J       K

FLAGS:  PROB:   ODDS:

1       4.600%  21.74

11      3.800%  26.32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just handled the case where is was completely surrounded by commas and the wild card before and after, and if it was first no wild card or comma on the left side..

```
 =SUMIF(B5:B64,"*," &I15&",*",C5:C64)+SUMIF(B5:B64,I15&",*",C5:C64)
```